# Unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_OLD_FUNCTION or T_FUNCTION or T_VAR

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to run a WordPress plugin, and I get the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_OLD_FUNCTION
or T_FUNCTION or T_VAR or '}' in
/nfs/c03/h05/mnt/52704/domains/creathive.net/html/wp-content/plugins/qr-code-tag/lib/qrct/QrctWp.php
on line 13
```

What would cause this error? Line 13 is the public bit.

EDIT: Here is some code:

```
class QrctWp
{
    public $pluginName = 'QR Code Tag';
```

Comment: We need to see more code.  There's going to be some sort of syntax error either before or after Line 13.

Comment: Yep to the above, that's the usual cause for the ol' unexpected T_STRING-er

Comment: I'm guessing a missing ; or an unclosed single or double-quote

Comment: That's not really enough code to go on.

Comment: Well the error is line 13 and im showing line 13?

Comment: The error is on line 13, but can be caused by something before line 13

Comment: but that's all there is before line 13

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Running on PHP4 by any chance? That's what the error message at this location would usually indicate.

Remove all `public` and `private` attributes. Though it's unlikely the plugin will work perfectly with the older object instance handling.

Comment: Yup just checked my htaccess file and it seems someone or something had removed the PHP5 handler.

Comment: This was helpful.  I realized I was running PHP4 on an old server.