# CakePHP Console doesn't work -> Parse Error

Tags: php, cakephp, console, cakephp-2.0

I'm working on two different CakePHP projects.
Both hosting on the same Server. One is on version 2.4.1 and the other one on 2.4.6.

On the last one i get an error if i want to use cake console.

```
Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_OLD_FUNCTION
or T_FUNCTION or T_VAR or '}' in /lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php on line 31
```

Google says it's a problem with my php version. But both are on 4.4.9 (cli) and on 5.2.17 / 5.3.19 (for the page).

*update*

```
    <?php
/**
 * ShellDispatcher file
 *
 * CakePHP(tm) : Rapid Development Framework (http://cakephp.org)
 * Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 *
 * Licensed under The MIT License
 * For full copyright and license information, please see the LICENSE.txt
 * Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
 *
 * @copyright     Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 * @link          http://cakephp.org CakePHP(tm) Project
 * @since         CakePHP(tm) v 2.0
 * @license       http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php MIT License
 */

/**
 * Shell dispatcher handles dispatching cli commands.
 *
 * @package       Cake.Console
 */
class ShellDispatcher {

/**
 * Contains command switches parsed from the command line.
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $params = array();

/**
 * Contains arguments parsed from the command line.
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $args = array();

/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * The execution of the script is stopped after dispatching the request with
 * a status code of either 0 or 1 according to the result of the dispatch.
 *
 * @param array $args the argv from PHP
 * @param boolean $bootstrap Should the environment be bootstrapped.
 */
    public function __construct($args = array(), $bootstrap = true) {
        set_time_limit(0);
        $this->parseParams($args);

        if ($bootstrap) {
            $this->_initConstants();
            $this->_initEnvironment();
        }
    }

/**
 * Run the dispatcher
 *
 * @param array $argv The argv from PHP
 * @return void
 */
    public static function run($argv) {
        $dispatcher = new ShellDispatcher($argv);
        return $dispatcher->_stop($dispatcher->dispatch() === false ? 1 : 0);
    }

/**
 * Defines core configuration.
 *
 * @return void
 */
    protected function _initConstants() {
        if (function_exists('ini_set')) {
            ini_set('html_errors', false);
            ini_set('implicit_flush', true);
            ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
        }

        if (!defined('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH')) {
            define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
            define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))));
            define('CAKEPHP_SHELL', true);
            if (!defined('CORE_PATH')) {
                define('CORE_PATH', CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH . DS);
            }
        }
    }

/**
 * Defines current working environment.
 *
 * @return void
 * @throws CakeException
 */
    protected function _initEnvironment() {
        if (!$this->_bootstrap()) {
            $message = "Unable to load CakePHP core.\nMake sure " . DS . 'lib' . DS . 'Cake exists in ' . CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH;
            throw new CakeException($message);
        }

        if (!isset($this->args[0]) || !isset($this->params['working'])) {
            $message = "This file has been loaded incorrectly and cannot continue.\n" .
                "Please make sure that " . DS . 'lib' . DS . 'Cake' . DS . "Console is in your system path,\n" .
                "and check the cookbook for the correct usage of this command.\n" .
                "(http://book.cakephp.org/)";
            throw new CakeException($message);
        }

        $this->shiftArgs();
    }

/**
 * Initializes the environment and loads the CakePHP core.
 *
 * @return boolean Success.
 */
    protected function _bootstrap() {
        if (!defined('ROOT')) {
            define('ROOT', $this->params['root']);
        }
        if (!defined('APP_DIR')) {
            define('APP_DIR', $this->params['app']);
        }
        if (!defined('APP')) {
            define('APP', $this->params['working'] . DS);
        }
        if (!defined('WWW_ROOT')) {
            define('WWW_ROOT', APP . $this->params['webroot'] . DS);
        }
        if (!defined('TMP') && !is_dir(APP . 'tmp')) {
            define('TMP', CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH . DS . 'Cake' . DS . 'Console' . DS . 'Templates' . DS . 'skel' . DS . 'tmp' . DS);
        }
        $boot = file_exists(ROOT . DS . APP_DIR . DS . 'Config' . DS . 'bootstrap.php');
        require CORE_PATH . 'Cake' . DS . 'bootstrap.php';

        if (!file_exists(APP . 'Config' . DS . 'core.php')) {
            include_once CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH . DS . 'Cake' . DS . 'Console' . DS . 'Templates' . DS . 'skel' . DS . 'Config' . DS . 'core.php';
            App::build();
        }

        $this->setErrorHandlers();

        if (!defined('FULL_BASE_URL')) {
            $url = Configure::read('App.fullBaseUrl');
            define('FULL_BASE_URL', $url ? $url : 'http://localhost');
            Configure::write('App.fullBaseUrl', FULL_BASE_URL);
        }

        return true;
    }

/**
 * Set the error/exception handlers for the console
 * based on the `Error.consoleHandler`, and `Exception.consoleHandler` values
 * if they are set. If they are not set, the default ConsoleErrorHandler will be
 * used.
 *
 * @return void
 */
    public function setErrorHandlers() {
        App::uses('ConsoleErrorHandler', 'Console');
        $error = Configure::read('Error');
        $exception = Configure::read('Exception');

        $errorHandler = new ConsoleErrorHandler();
        if (empty($error['consoleHandler'])) {
            $error['consoleHandler'] = array($errorHandler, 'handleError');
            Configure::write('Error', $error);
        }
        if (empty($exception['consoleHandler'])) {
            $exception['consoleHandler'] = array($errorHandler, 'handleException');
            Configure::write('Exception', $exception);
        }
        set_exception_handler($exception['consoleHandler']);
        set_error_handler($error['consoleHandler'], Configure::read('Error.level'));
    }

/**
 * Dispatches a CLI request
 *
 * @return boolean
 * @throws MissingShellMethodException
 */
    public function dispatch() {
        $shell = $this->shiftArgs();

        if (!$shell) {
            $this->help();
            return false;
        }
        if (in_array($shell, array('help', '--help', '-h'))) {
            $this->help();
            return true;
        }

        $Shell = $this->_getShell($shell);

        $command = null;
        if (isset($this->args[0])) {
            $command = $this->args[0];
        }

        if ($Shell instanceof Shell) {
            $Shell->initialize();
            return $Shell->runCommand($command, $this->args);
        }
        $methods = array_diff(get_class_methods($Shell), get_class_methods('Shell'));
        $added = in_array($command, $methods);
        $private = $command[0] === '_' && method_exists($Shell, $command);

        if (!$private) {
            if ($added) {
                $this->shiftArgs();
                $Shell->startup();
                return $Shell->{$command}();
            }
            if (method_exists($Shell, 'main')) {
                $Shell->startup();
                return $Shell->main();
            }
        }

        throw new MissingShellMethodException(array('shell' => $shell, 'method' => $command));
    }

/**
 * Get shell to use, either plugin shell or application shell
 *
 * All paths in the loaded shell paths are searched.
 *
 * @param string $shell Optionally the name of a plugin
 * @return mixed An object
 * @throws MissingShellException when errors are encountered.
 */
    protected function _getShell($shell) {
        list($plugin, $shell) = pluginSplit($shell, true);

        $plugin = Inflector::camelize($plugin);
        $class = Inflector::camelize($shell) . 'Shell';

        App::uses('Shell', 'Console');
        App::uses('AppShell', 'Console/Command');
        App::uses($class, $plugin . 'Console/Command');

        if (!class_exists($class)) {
            throw new MissingShellException(array(
                'class' => $class
            ));
        }
        $Shell = new $class();
        $Shell->plugin = trim($plugin, '.');
        return $Shell;
    }

/**
 * Parses command line options and extracts the directory paths from $params
 *
 * @param array $args Parameters to parse
 * @return void
 */
    public function parseParams($args) {
        $this->_parsePaths($args);

        $defaults = array(
            'app' => 'app',
            'root' => dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))),
            'working' => null,
            'webroot' => 'webroot'
        );
        $params = array_merge($defaults, array_intersect_key($this->params, $defaults));
        $isWin = false;
        foreach ($defaults as $default => $value) {
            if (strpos($params[$default], '\\') !== false) {
                $isWin = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        $params = str_replace('\\', '/', $params);

        if (isset($params['working'])) {
            $params['working'] = trim($params['working']);
        }

        if (!empty($params['working']) && (!isset($this->args[0]) || isset($this->args[0]) && $this->args[0][0] !== '.')) {
            if ($params['working'][0] === '.') {
                $params['working'] = realpath($params['working']);
            }
            if (empty($this->params['app']) && $params['working'] != $params['root']) {
                $params['root'] = dirname($params['working']);
                $params['app'] = basename($params['working']);
            } else {
                $params['root'] = $params['working'];
            }
        }

        if ($params['app'][0] === '/' || preg_match('/([a-z])(:)/i', $params['app'], $matches)) {
            $params['root'] = dirname($params['app']);
        } elseif (strpos($params['app'], '/')) {
            $params['root'] .= '/' . dirname($params['app']);
        }

        $params['app'] = basename($params['app']);
        $params['working'] = rtrim($params['root'], '/');
        if (!$isWin || !preg_match('/^[A-Z]:$/i', $params['app'])) {
            $params['working'] .= '/' . $params['app'];
        }

        if (!empty($matches[0]) || !empty($isWin)) {
            $params = str_replace('/', '\\', $params);
        }

        $this->params = array_merge($this->params, $params);
    }

/**
 * Parses out the paths from from the argv
 *
 * @param array $args
 * @return void
 */
    protected function _parsePaths($args) {
        $parsed = array();
        $keys = array('-working', '--working', '-app', '--app', '-root', '--root');
        foreach ($keys as $key) {
            while (($index = array_search($key, $args)) !== false) {
                $keyname = str_replace('-', '', $key);
                $valueIndex = $index + 1;
                $parsed[$keyname] = $args[$valueIndex];
                array_splice($args, $index, 2);
            }
        }
        $this->args = $args;
        $this->params = $parsed;
    }

/**
 * Removes first argument and shifts other arguments up
 *
 * @return mixed Null if there are no arguments otherwise the shifted argument
 */
    public function shiftArgs() {
        return array_shift($this->args);
    }

/**
 * Shows console help. Performs an internal dispatch to the CommandList Shell
 *
 * @return void
 */
    public function help() {
        $this->args = array_merge(array('command_list'), $this->args);
        $this->dispatch();
    }

/**
 * Stop execution of the current script
 *
 * @param integer|string $status see http://php.net/exit for values
 * @return void
 */
    protected function _stop($status = 0) {
        exit($status);
    }

}
```

Comment: what's the code around line 31 in `/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php`?

Comment: line 31 ist empty. line 30 is:  public $params = array();

Comment: Can you update with code in ShellDispacher.php?

Comment: You must've forgot to close the class or a function.

Comment: code added, but i havent changed it. it's a core file of cakephp. AND it works on the other project.

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719688/unexpected-t-string-expecting-t-old-function-or-t-function-or-t-var

Comment: Why don't you try using its own cakephp console for itself which is found ".../lib/Cake/Console/cake"?

Comment: Solution: edited cake-script and changed php-call to "exec php.5 -q ...". now it uses php cli version 5 and not 4. Thanks to all your answers.